# strange error with unicode translation

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have some trouble with this piece of code:

```
print "Таблица Unicode (русские буквы)".center(18*4)
i = 0

for c in "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"\
         "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя":
  u = unicode(c, 'koi8-r')
```

Here I try to translate russian letters into Unicode but get error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

But if I try it manually like:

```
u = unicode('A', 'koi8-r')
u = unicode('Б', 'koi8-r')
```

everything is ok. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is stored in the KOI8-R encoding? And not, for example, UTF-8 (or ISO-8859-1)?

Comment: Stupid I!!! I forgot to add # -*- coding:koi8-r -*-

Comment: But now russian words are displayed wrongly(((

Comment: `#!coding: koi8-r` declares the source file encoding.  The source file *must* be saved in that encoding or your will get incorrect characters.  Then use Unicode strings as @Ignacio suggested.

Comment: The problem is that you have a byte string containing UTF-8 characters, and the `for c in` only gives you a single byte of a multi-byte sequence. Try printing `len('Б')` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unicode` literals in the first place.

```
print u"Таблица Unicode (русские буквы)".center(18*4)

for c in (u"АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
          u"абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"):
  print c
```

Comment: Also good to note that the source file and source encoding declaration should agree.